# How can I call a function that performs a transfer in web3?

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-invocation

I would like to call a function in smart contract using web3. In the function, I perform few transactions.

The first method that I tried is `await myContract.methods.endAuction().call();`. This reverted the transaction with the error message "Auction owner is not authorized" which is strange since I succedded in calling previous function from the same smart contract which had the same restriction.

The second method I tried is `await myContract.methods.endAuction().plasticBaleSC.methods.endAuction().send({from: accounts[0]});` which caused the transaction to fail with no revert message.

The function that I want to call is this:

```
function endAuction() onlyOwner public{
        
        require( isOpen, "Auction is not avalible.");
        require(endTime < now, "Auction duration is not up yet.");
        require(highestBidder != address(0), "No bids have been placed"); 
        
        isOpen = false; 
        
        uint halfAmount = highestBid/2;
    
        (auctionOwner).transfer(halfAmount); 

        uint contributionRate =0; 
        uint reward; 
        
        
        for(uint i=0; i < contributors.length; i++){
                uint j;
             for(j=0; j < i; j++)
                  if(contributors[i] == contributors[j])
                      break;
                if(i==j)
                tempArray.push(contributors[i]);
              }
        

        for(uint i=0; i < tempArray.length; i++){
            contribution=0;
             for(uint z=0; z < contributors.length; z++){
                  if(tempArray[i] == contributors[z])
                      contribution++;
             }
             contribution = contribution *100; 
             contributionRate = contribution / (plasticBale.length);
             reward = ((contributionRate * halfAmount)/ 100)+1;
             tempArray[i].transfer(reward); 
             rewardRecycler(tempArray[i], reward); 
    
        }
          
          for(uint i=0; i< plasticBale.length; i++)
          updateBottleStatus(highestBidder, plasticBale[i]); 
          
        emit auctionEnded(address(this), highestBidder, highestBid , now); 
    
    }


modifier onlyOwner{
        require(msg.sender == auctionOwner, "Auction owner is not authorized"); 
        _; 
    }
```

Any advice on what should I do?

Edit: This is a link to the full contract code although you might want to remove the modifiers for now since onlyBuyer interfaces with another smart contract [EthFiddle](https://ethfiddle.com/McViSm9Tqz)

Answer (score 0):

Let's begin from here - you should use `.call()` for contract methods which are only reading from the blockchain ( methods which are not updating the state of the smart contract ) and you should use `.send()` for methods which are writing on the blockchain ( methods which are updating the state of the smart contract ).

Now when we cleared this and when we know that your method `endAuction()` is actually updating the state of the contract, you should use `await myContract.methods.endAuction().send({from: accounts[0]})`. If it's still failing make sure `accounts[0]` has proper value and when you make sure everything looks ok with the frontend part then start inspecting the contract. You have a modifier `onlyOwner` and 3 different requires at the top of the method which might cause the transaction reverting.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the reply! I did try to use `send({from: account[0]})` but the transaction failed. While testing the smart contract in remix, calling the function without setting a value seems to work.

Comment: Hey, attach in the question your full JS code and the full smart contract code. Also did you debug if ```accounts[0]``` is not an empty value?

Comment: I'm using metamask so account[0] is not empty. I will link the smart contract and the JS file shortly, although, they are very long.

Comment: I tested the smart contract on remix using the injected web3 environment, when calling the endAuction function, I get this error message https://ibb.co/dG7j092

Comment: Then your javascript part is fine, now you need to start debugging the smart contract method. It's not a simple method, it includes few requires and few for loops which might cause the problem.